# React Native useState string with conditional rendering

Tags: react-native, jsx

I am attempting to do if statements the same way I would normally with useState however it is failing.

I have these values

```
let [L01, setL01] = useState('');
let [L02, setL02] = useState('');

let [level01, setlevel01] = useState(false);
let [level01_Open, setlevel01_Open] = useState(false);
let [level01_img, setlevel01_img] = useState(false);
let [locked_level01, setlocked_level01] = useState(false);

let [level02, setlevel02] = useState(false);
let [level02_Open, setlevel02_Open] = useState(false);
let [level02_img, setlevel02_img] = useState(false);
let [locked_level02, setlocked_level02] = useState(false);
```

L01 then gets set to  'Yes' while L02 gets set to 'No'

I then attempt to my run if statements based on that data however it is recognizing L01 as Yes however it fails to set the values within the if statmenet to true.

```
 if ( L01 == 'Yes') {
        setlevel01(true)
        setlevel02_Open(true)
        setlevel01_img(true)
       } else {
        setlevel01(false)
        setlevel02_Open(false)
        setlevel01_img(false)
       }

       if ( L02 == 'Yes') {
        setlevel02(true) 
        setlevel01_img(false)
        setlevel02_img(true)
       } else  {
        setlevel02(true)
        setlevel02_img(false)
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set an effect hook using `useEffect` to watch `L01` and `L02` for changes:

```jsx
useEffect(() => {
  // Define any login and state update here when  L01 or L02 change

  const L01Flag = L01 === 'Yes';
  setlevel01(L01Flag);
  setlevel02_Open(L01Flag);
  setlevel01_img(L01Flag);

  const L02Flag = L02 === 'Yes';
  setlevel02(L02Flag);
  setlevel01_Open(L02Flag);
  setlevel02_img(L02Flag);

}, [L01, L02]);
```

Comment: AH! Thank you. The actual part of your answer which helped me was the fact that I needed a completely separate useEffect for this as I had one to originally set the data.
Question though. Why does it need me to create a array at the end of the useEffect? What benefit does that provide as I do not do that on my first useEffect?

Comment: The array at the end of `useEffect` actually tells `useEffect` when to execute. In out case `useEffect` will execute **ONLY** when one of `L01` or `L02` changes.

Comment: What if your pulling data from a database to set L01 or L02 to Yes or No and because of React Natives ordering you have to pull that data pull after the useEffect? Because in my first UseEffect that is what I do so if I include the array after it creates a error saying it can not read the property because the data isn't there.

Comment: You'll have to set a `useEffect` hook to pull data as well. When you pass an empty array to the end of `useEffect`, then that hook runs only once and then it's like `componentdidMount` in class components and you can load DB data in there then then update the state.

Comment: Ah that makes sense so If I do that like this then: 
let [ data, setData ] = useState(useQuery(GetLevelsQuery));
How do I deconstruct the data return to set the variables L01 and L02?

Comment: `useQuery` is from Apollo GraphQL server?

Comment: Yes it is from Apollo GraphQL server.